# Windows compilation error when running a small program

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

When I ran my solution to The Square Within from codercharts.com on my computer (Intel i5 newest version), I was able to build my program in 646 ms, but for some random reason I was able to enter the code for the input part of my code, but when I pressed "enter" to get results, the screen popped up with a Windows error:

[image: windows error]

Here is my code that I ran (logic all follows the problem I was given).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int dimension[]={};
    int result;
    int counter = 0;
        for (int i=0; i < 1000000; i++){
            counter+=1;
            }
        for (int a=0; a<counter; a++){
            result=(dimension[a]*(dimension[a] + 1)*((2*dimension[a]) + 1))/6;
        }
    while (true){
        cin >> dimension[counter];
        break;
        cout << result << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can something review my code and help me with this hard problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `int dimension[]={};` I don't think that array is going to be big enough ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
int dimension[]={};
```

needs a value for its size:

i.e.

```
int dimension[1000001]={};
```

Comment: I tried what you recommended, but I still got the error.

Comment: Now I can't even run the code in the first place-it doesn't allow me to even enter a value before the error pops up

Comment: What do I do to fix it now? I have done what you recommended, but my code still produces the same error. @EdHeal

Comment: you changed 1000000 to 1000001, but that doesn't do anything. My code still has the error.

Comment: That object might be too big for the stack.  If so, you could use a `std::vector<int>`.